# Разрушение сессии через определенный промежуток времени

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

При получении `access_token` от ВК приходит следующий массив:

```
Array
(
    [access_token] =>
    [expires_in] => 86398
    [user_id] =>
    [email] =>
)
```

В самой документации сказано следующее:

> В результате выполнения данного запроса Ваш сервер получит вновь
>   созданный access_token. Вместе с access_token серверу возвращается
>   время жизни ключа expires_in в секундах.

Исходя из этого осмелюсь предположить, что `expires_in` это время жизни сессии. Однако сейчас сессия разрушается при завершении сеанса браузера.

[image: При завершении сеанса браузера]

Как установить сессии полученное значение `expires_in`, а по истечении данного отрезка времени разрушить сессию, чтобы пользователю пришлось авторизоваться повторно?

**UPB**

Объяснили немножко в коментах, что я не правильно понял. Однако суть не меняется. Если даже `expires_in` это время жизни токина, а по истечении этого времени пользователь останется за логиным - то запросы к api он все равно делать не сможет. Поэтому нужно разрушить сессию через это время.

Comment: `expires_in` это НЕ время жизни сессии. Это время жизни токена. А сессией управлять должны вы.

Comment: Алексей, спасибо что объяснил, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Если вы именно хотите разрушать сессию а не переобновлять `access_token`, то вам надо посмотреть в сторону `cookie_lifetime` - указывает время жизни cookies, отправляемого в браузер клиента, в секундах. Значение 0 означает, что cookies будут валидны до закрытия браузера.http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime ..... если смотреть пример тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php  то можно написать `session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
]);`  для теста, можете сделать новую страничку и написать код для проверки:

Comment: `$lifeTime = 10;
session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => $lifeTime,
]);

if (!isset($_SESSION['expired'])) {
 $_SESSION['expired'] = time();
   echo "Добро пожаловать на наш сайт!";
} else {      
      echo "Вы впервые пришли на наш сайт ".(time()-$_SESSION['expired'])." секунд назад";
}` ........а вообще если можно просто перезапрашивать токен по истечению времени.... и кстати если в `scope` авторизации указать `offline` то выдается вечный токен....ну это так, на всякий случай

Answer (score 1):

Не храните эти данные в PHP сессии. Можно использовать любое хранилище имеющее возможность устанавливать expires (Redis и ему подобные). Можно хранить и в куках с таким же временем жизни, но придется шифровать, если в данных есть что то секретное. Да хоть обычную реляционную БД можно использовать. Просто при очередном запросе проверять актуальность. И не нужно ничего разрушать. Просто получать новый токен при истечении актуальности старого.